# Pyplot issues in horizontal bar chart

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting the following data (stored as 'sample_bar_plot.csv' in C:\Plot):

```
    X           Y
A   12.60862266 13.88257739
B   18.69422707 20.66625712
C   13.54164413 18.49381352
D   11.35545631 13.12407667
E   9.979860808 11.33701054
F   8.496320019 8.838461563
G   11.94646631 16.28188825
```

Python code to draw horizontal output is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math, pdb, csv
import pylab, operator
from matplotlib import rcParams

base_dir  = 'C:\\Plot\\'
file_name = 'sample_bar_plot.csv'
header    = True
csv_data  = {}

with open(base_dir+file_name, mode='r') as infile:
    reader   = csv.reader(infile)
    for rows in reader:
        if header == True:
            header = False
            continue
        else:
            csv_data[rows[0]]=rows[1:3]

print csv_data

num_keys = len(csv_data.keys())
num_vals = len(csv_data.values()[0])

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
ax = fig.add_axes([0.15, 0.15, 0.65, 0.7])
# remove top and right spines and turn ticks off if no spine
ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(size=0)
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
# postition of tick out
ax.tick_params(axis='bottom', direction='in', width=2, length=6,
                   labelsize=24, pad=8)

ax.spines['left'].set_linewidth(2)
ax.spines['bottom'].set_linewidth(2)
ax.set_yticklabels(['']+csv_data.keys())   
rcParams['ytick.direction'] = 'out'

# Find maximum value in dictionary
max_val = 0.0
for i,key in enumerate(csv_data.keys()):
    if(float(csv_data.values()[i][0]) > max_val):
        max_val = float(csv_data.values()[i][0])
    if(float(csv_data.values()[i][1]) > max_val):
        max_val = float(csv_data.values()[i][1])

plt.ylim((0,num_keys+1))
plt.xlim((0,int(max_val+5)))

idx = 1
for i,key in enumerate(csv_data.keys()):
    ax.barh([idx],float(csv_data.values()[idx-1][1]), height=0.1, facecolor='0.75',edgecolor='k', linewidth=0,align='center')
    cir = pylab.Circle((float(csv_data.values()[idx-1][1]),idx), radius=0.2,  fc='0.75',linewidth=0)
    pylab.gca().add_patch(cir)

    ax.barh([idx],float(csv_data.values()[idx-1][0]), height=0.1, facecolor='k',edgecolor='k', linewidth=0,align='center')
    cir = pylab.Circle((float(csv_data.values()[idx-1][0]),idx), radius=0.2,  fc='k',linewidth=0)
    pylab.gca().add_patch(cir)

    idx += 1   

plt.savefig(base_dir+'out.png')
plt.show()
```

However, the plot has several issues:
1. The circles seem more like ellipses. How can I correct that?
2. The x-axis ticks should be outwards not inwards, but again code is behaving opposite.
3. Several of the lines are thicker than the rest (e.g. 'A', 'B' and 'F'

Can anyone suggest how these can be overcome?

thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your first a few lines to these and you will be all set,

I can't reproduce your #3.

Your #1 is an aspect issue.
For #2, you need to change the `rcParams`

```
num_keys = len(csv_data.keys())
num_vals = len(csv_data.values()[0])
rcParams['xtick.direction'] = 'out'
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
ax = fig.add_axes([0.15, 0.15, 0.65, 0.7], aspect='equal')
```

You defined the figure size. Therefore it we set the aspect to `equal`. There will be a large area of white space, see figure attachment.

[image]

Comment: Is there any way teh spacing between ticks on the X and Y-axis be made the same? Currently, the distance between ticks on X axis is way more than the Y axis....thanks!

Comment: Actually in `equal aspect`, `x` ticks and `y ticks` are the same length/unit. Here it looks different because `x` major ticks are 5 units apart and `y` major ticks are 1 unit apart. Change all the `[idx]` to `[idx*5]`, `,idx)` to `,5*idx)`, `ylim` to `plt.ylim((0,5*num_keys+5))`will do it. Or add: `from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator; 
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(1))` to addjust `x` `majorticks`.